# Não consigo setar no textField JAVA

Tags: java, swing

Possuo este frame, onde ao clicar no botão 'BUSCAR PRODUTO' abre outro frame com a listagem dos produtos cadastrados:

```
public class GeracaoOcamento extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     public GeracaoOcamento() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void retornaID(ListaProdutos frameProdutos, int idSelecionado) {
        ProdutoDAO pd = new ProdutoDAO();
        Produto produto = pd.buscarPorId(Produto.class, idSelecionado);

        lblNomeProduto.setText(produto.getNome());
        lblNumero.setText("2018/");
        System.out.println(produto.getNome());

    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new ListaClientes().setVisible(true);
    }                                        


    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        new ListaProdutos().setVisible(true);        

    }                                       


}
```

Neste frame possui uma tabela de produtos. Ao dar um duplo click em uma linha, recupero o id do produto da linha clicada e retorno este id para o frame anterior. segue o código:

```
public class ListaProdutos extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ListaClientes
     */
    public ProdutoTableModel tableModel;
    ProdutoDAO produtodao = new ProdutoDAO();
    GeracaoOcamento geracaoOrcamento = new GeracaoOcamento();

    public ListaProdutos() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        tableModel = new ProdutoTableModel(produtodao.consultarTodos());

        tableLista.setModel(tableModel);
    }


    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        CadastroProduto cp = new CadastroProduto();
        //DeskPane.add(cp);
        cp.setVisible(true);

        this.setVisible(false);

    }                           

    private void tableListaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

        if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int linha = tableLista.getSelectedRow();
            int idSelecionado = (int) tableModel.getValueAt(linha, 0);
            geracaoOrcamento.retornaID(this, idSelecionado);
            this.dispose();
    }                                       
    }


}
```

No método de retorno do ID da Classe GeraçãoOrcamento, eu utilizo o dado retorno e busco no banco de dados o produto equivalente.

Pego as informações deste produto e tento setar em uma TextField.

o problema é que não seta. Consigo imprimir o valor no System out normalmente, como teste. 
mas o valor não é setado no campo de texto dentro deste método.

Código completo aqui --> https://github.com/loardjulio/SoftFlor.git

Comment: Julio, forneça o que você ja fez, no formato de um codigo que seja **[mcve]** para que possamos executar e testar o problema.

Comment: Também recomendo que leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: Articuno, Cara mil perdões. Ja deu para ver que sou novo por aqui né. Refiz todo o tópico buscando atender as normas. Fiquei envergonhado kkkk. Desculpe e Obrigado

Comment: Julio, voce ainda nao forneceu o que eu sugeri, recomendo que acesse o link e crie um código que seja testavel e resumido, afinal, não é nada legal forçar quem quer te ajudar a ter que baixar seu projeto todo e acessando de links externos. Recomendo que crie um exemplo conforme o primeiro link.

Comment: Acho que ja entendi o problema, o problema é que você está usando vários JFrames, quando o recomendado é usar apenas um para a tela principal, e telas modais para demais funçoes secundárias, como recuperar dados, que é o caso do seu problema, veja as respostas das perguntas da caixa amarela, nela eu explico algumas solucoes para problemas semelhantes ao seu e em uma delas ensina como usar modais em java-swing, através de JDialog.s

Comment: Valeu. Obrigado